# javascript array using for loop

Tags: javascript

I have to display like this please explain.
    here 4 means no. of years

```
var categories = [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018];
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getFullYear();
for (var i = 0; i <= date + 4; i++) {
    var categories2 = [];
    categories2[i] = date;
    date++;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Print?

Comment: This will be an infinite loop because `date++` and `i++` mean that `i` will never reach `date + 4`.  Also `categories2` will get emptied each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got it.

```
     var d = new Date();
       var start = d.getFullYear();
       categories = Array();
       for(i = start; i <= start+4; i++)
       categories .push(i);

alert(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Andy's right - although it's debatable whether date+4 is re-accessed every iteration of the loop.

Try:

```
var categories = [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018];
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getFullYear();
var categories2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= date + 4; i++)   
    categories2[i] = date+i;
```